# v-select dropdown shows outside the v-dialog

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify 2.3.10. I have the following piece of code and the issue I am facing here is that the select dropdown for v-select appear on top of the page rather than in the dialog box attached to the v-select. I guess there is some issue with the position css property of the dropdown. How can I resolve this?

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12>
      <div class='selection portal'>
        <v-dialog v-model='select_location' id="change-location-dialog" >
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>
              <h3>Select Location</h3>
              <v-select v-model="selectedLocation"
                        persistent
                        attach="#change-location-dialog"
                        placeholder="Select Location"
                        :items='locations'
                        item-text='name'
                        item-value='id'
                        max-width="250">
              </v-select>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn @click="picklocation">Ok</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `attach="#change-location-dialog` on the `<v-select/>` and it should be fine. I guess what happens is that, it tries to attach the selection menu on the dialog, including its backdrop which covers the whole page so it appears on top. By removing the `attach` prop, it will be attached to the `<v-select/>` textfield by default.

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-meadow-8z3qu?file=/src/components/Playground.vue):

[image]